# Comment Author Link on Wordpress for all comments

Tags: wordpress, comments

[Comment Author Link on Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742246/comment-author-link-on-wordpress)

This is a question based on the solution provided in above post.

There it replace the comment author link for those who dont have a link.
Is it possible to do this for all comments. (all comment authors will be linked to author page")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you try this

```
function force_comment_author_url($comment)
{
    // does the comment have a valid author URL?
    $no_url = !$comment->comment_author_url || $comment->comment_author_url == 'http://';


    $comment->comment_author_url = get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id);

   return $comment;
}
add_filter('get_comment', 'force_comment_author_url');
```

[get_author_posts_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) docs